# Regex to replace text between (outside) two tags

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to use some regex to wrap the word "or" in a `<span>` tag in some markup.

```html
<div id="test">
  <a href="#" class="thickbox open-details-modal" aria-label="View version 1.5.29 details">View version 1.5.29 details</a> or <a href="#" class="update-link" aria-label="Update now">update now</a>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
var html = $( '#test' ).html();

html = html.replace( /(<\/a>[\s\S]*?<a)/, "<\/a><span class='or'>$1<\/span><a href" );

$( '#result' ).html( html );
```

The resulting markup is a bit strange:

```
<div id="result">
  <a href="#" class="thickbox open-details-modal" aria-label="View version 1.5.29 details">View version 1.5.29 details</a><span class="or"> or <a< span=""><a href="" class="update-link" aria-label="Update now">update now</a>
</a<></span></div>
```

The result nests the second `<a> inside of the`` element. I can't seem to wrap my head around why it's nesting in such a weird way.

```
<span class="or"> or <a< span=""><a href="" class="update-link" aria-label="Update now">update now</a>
</a<></span>
```

I've got a fiddle where I was testing some things here: https://jsfiddle.net/qfuLozxw/

**Intended results:**

```
<div id="test">
  <a href="#" class="thickbox open-details-modal" aria-label="View version 1.5.29 details">View version 1.5.29 details</a> <span class="or">or</span> <a href="#" class="update-link" aria-label="Update now">update now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags -> don't parse (X)HTML with regex.  Use a parser.

Comment: You were trying to get https://regex101.com/r/Uxjcka/1. But you should really parse the HTML with HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

The content matched inside your parenthesis is what gets returned in the `$1` variable. You just need to contain the text you want to replace:

```
html = html.replace( /<\/a>( or )<a/, "<\/a><span class='or'>$1</span><a" );
```

Or if you want to match on any word inbetween your links:

```
html = html.replace( /<\/a>( \w* )<a/, "</a><span class='or'>$1</span><a" );
```

Example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/wbard38q/

Comment: Did that help or are you still having issues?